# How can I synchronize github with a local repository?

Tags: git, github

I didn't find a clear answer to this one (many things are overwhelming to newbies at git):

I have a local repo and a remote at github consisting of files: A, B and C.

- This morning I changed local file A.
- At noon, remote B was changed.
- Later on, I decided to change some comments at **local** file C **and** some code at **remote** C.

My draw depicts the files and their changes:

```
local       remote
 A  ------->   A
 B  <-------   B
 C  <------>   C
```

In the evening, I'm just staring the repos. Is there any chance to finish promptly? Anyone?

Comment: @jessh Should note some things here: immediately after doing `pull` we should do a `git reset A` otherwise the **remote** A will **overwrite the newest local A**! Then add and commit (**but**, if your local C is newest then, it will be lost!) My project https://github.com/centurianii/g3measure

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ trying to understand `stash`...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commit all of your local changes first. Make sure your working directory is clean:

```
$ git status
```

should return: `nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Then, pull in the remote's changes:

```
$ git pull remote-name branch-name
# it's probably git pull origin master
```

Then push your changes to share with the remote:

```
$ git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

My local workfolw allows your to untie the pull and push stages properly, and it is the following:

1. Store your local uncommitted changes with `git stash`:

   ```
   git stash
   ```
2. Update your local repo with remote version one:

   ```
   git pull
   ```

   So you get:

   ```
   local       remote
   B  <-------   B
   C  <-------   C
   ```
3. Apply local changes, and merge all inconsistiences, fix the files if any require, and add them into index, and commit merge:

   ```
   git stash pop
   vim ...
   git add .
   git commit
   ```
4. Edit file `C`, and commit it.

   ```
   vim C
   git add C
   git commit
   ```
5. Push changes into remove repo:

   ```
   git push
   ```

   So you'll get:

   ```
   local       remote
   A  ------->   B
   C  ------->   C
   ```